# Как правильно сделать авторизацию с помощью PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Я впервые пробую PDO и впервые делаю регистрацию и авторизацию.

С регистрацией проблем не было. Но теперь с fectchAll независимо от обстоятельств выдает пустой массив.

Я хочу понять где я допустил ошибки и как сделать правильно?
Вот код:

```
<?php
    require 'connectDB.php';

    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // sql запрос в базу
    $sql = "'SELECT FROM * `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password'";

    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $user = $query->fetchAll();

    if (count($user) == 0) {
        echo '<script>alert("Такой пользователь не найден")</script>';
        exit();
    }

    print_r($user);
    exit();

//    $query->execute([
//        'login' => $login,
//        'password' => $password
//    ]);
```

Лично мне кажется я не совсем хорошо обрабатываю sql запрос. Но если я его нормально сделаю, то что мне дальше делать?

Comment: Я сейчас посидел на форумах, почитал, оказывается PDO использовать в данном случае бессмысленно? Если это так, то что нужно использовать, и как это сделать?

Comment: это на каком форуме такое написано?

Comment: а по сути - надо открыть документацию на функцию password_hash *и почитать, как с ней работать*

Comment: и вернуть execute назад

Comment: и потом можно будет написать ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: в базе точно хеши хранятся?

Comment: @Jean-Claude забавная догадка, но скорее всего она неверна. Здесь и без этого много ошибок, чтобы выдумывать еще какие-то причины

Comment: @Ипатьев увы, он мог из более сложного кода копировать кусочками и тупо пропустил строку

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ошибок у вас довольно много.** Некоторые из них:

В sql запросе в самом начале стоит лишний апостроф.
Также пишется `SELECT * FROM` , а не `SELECT FROM *`

Если вы делаете запрос в `prepare`, то для начала нужно ставить "заглушки", а не готовые значения. Готовые значения подставляем только в следующем шаге внутри `execute`. (Ниже есть пример)

Также очень важно, что если мы проверяем пароль, захешированный через `password_hash()`, проверить его корректность мы должны уже в другой функции -
`password_verify($password, $hash)`
где 1 параметром мы передаем введенный пароль пользователя,
а 2-м параметром **захешированный пароль** из базы

Поэтому убедитесь предварительно, что ваши пароли в базе хранятся уже в захешированном виде.

Так же не следует в данном случае применять функцию filter_var c фильтром FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, поскольку он может испортить логин и пароль, и они не совпадут.

*Все исправил и прокомментировал в коде ниже, можете сравнить со своим.*

```php
require 'connectDB.php';

$login = trim($_POST['login']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

// sql запрос в базу (знак "?" это заглушка
// в которую мы подставим значение в execute далее)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = ?";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
// Сейчас как раз подставляем значение в нашу "?" - загрушку выше.
$query->execute([$login]);
// В данном случае лучше использовать fetch вместо fetchAll,
// так ищем в базе только 1 совпадение
$user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Теперь проверяем правильный ли введен пароль
// с помощью password_verify()
if($user && password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
    echo 'Авторизация прошла успешно';
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("Такой пользователь не найден")</script>';
    exit();
}

//print_r($user);
```

Что касается константы `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` внутри `fetch`, - она нам возвращает только текстовые индексы. Это аналог `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Дмитрий, а давайте вы сначала прочитаете в документации, как пользоваться функцией  password_hash, а потом будете ответы писать?

Comment: @Ипатьев , не поверите, прежде чем писать ответ, я почитал. И не только в документации.

Comment: из мелких замечаний: 1. переменные в РНР пишутся **без** кавычек. В кавычках пишутся строки. Очень важно не путать эти два элемента языка. 2. убрать filter_var из кода, поскольку в данном случае они не нужны и только мешают. 3. "удобная" функция rowCount() на самом деле абсолютно бесполезна. Поскольку можно просто написать `if (!$user) {`

Comment: @Ипатьев , благодарю за замечание, подробнее ознакомился с password_hash и password_verify. *Изменил ответ.*

Comment: Очень хорошо, теперь правильно. Но не до конца. Во-первых, надо переписать так `if($user && password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {` иначе будет ошибка Undefined index если пользователь не найден. плюс имя поля указать правильно. Во-вторых, надо исправить остальные замечания. В комментарии про кавычки вообще какая-то чушь несусветная написана. Переменные в РНР пишутся **вообще без кавычек**

Comment: @Ипатьев , Да, спасибо, в if добавил ещё ```$user``` . Имя поля неправильно указал из-за того, что у себя с другой таблицей проверял работоспособность кода, там как раз "pass" стоял, забыл исправить.  
А по поводу кавычек, насколько я знаю, что если мы передаем более 1 переменной в execute, то их нужно в кавычки оборачивать.(я могу ошибаться)   Когда-то давно вроде у меня без них не работало, поэтому привык всегда в кавычки оборачивать, а в апострофах так не работает, поэтому решил написать об этом.  
Сейчас все поправил

Comment: Про кавычки это какая-то ерунда. Никакого специального синтаксиса для execute не существует. execute принимает на вход обычный массив. Чтобы в РНР написать массив, в него надо просто положить переменные, без всяких кавычек. Ещё надо убрать filter_var, потому что писать это здесь бессмысленно, но при этом можно испортить данные и запрос их не найдет

Comment: Надо понимать, что `$var` - это переменная, а "$var" - это строка. И никогда не писать строки вместо переменных. Потому что такая запись насильно переведет данные в строковый тип и тем самым их испортит. плюс это просто бессмысленно. Ну не пишут переменные в кавычках. Это как на кроссовки сверху носки надевать. Не смертельно, но просто глупо

Comment: Спасибо вам всем за проявленную помощь! Я смог разобраться!